# Want to make a left navigation Sidebar

Tags: html, css

So far I'm able to make the header bar, in a similar way I want to make a left sidebar with css applied.

**EDIT1:** How do I make the `id="wrapper"` to make both containing in one wrapper Or, let me know how can we make simply a sidebar accompanied with my top-bar.

**EDIT2**: This is the link to github [repository](https://github.com/sanchitdua/SidebarProblem) for more understanding.

Please let me know how can I make the same sidebar navigation like the header one.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't sidestep the So rule of posting your code in your question when linking to jsFiddle.net. If jsFiddle.net is ever sold or inaccessible, then your question loses all value.

Comment: @j08691 I'm sorry for any confusion. I have provided the github link. I was in a bit of urgency at that moment.

Answer (score -1):

Is this possibly what you are looking for see my example. http://cdpn.io/pDBlE. If so let me know, I will share code or you can leach it from the example.

Comment: Could you please review the github I have shared and let me know the possibilities from it.